# Magento 2.3 products not visible

Tags: catalog, products, magento2.3

After migrating data and products from Magento 1.9 I can see all my categories and products available in the backend. But not on the frontend.

I've checked all options;

- Products are "enabled"
- Products have stock + saleable stock
- Products are added to categories
- Products are added to website
- Set catalog to show out of stock products as well
- Using base-theme

And of course, reindexed and cache-cleaned countless times.

At some point I saw a few products show up after I changed the "Product has weight" toggle, but that doesn't seem to work anymore either.

And 1 thing changed; I see my layered navigation filled with the product choices, but the products themselves don't show. What am I missing?

See the [dev site here](https://solvermedia.dev/regenwaterpomp) to see for yourself.
I'm at a loss, what is going on?

Comment: check if table `inventory_stock_1` is in your view and not in table

Comment: Can you please check your server log, I am finding many 500 errors in the site.Also please check this report in var/reports/945691316147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above comments pointed me in the direction that something might've been wrong with file permissions as the `Could not read config file` error pops up everywhere. Also, this topic pointed me to possible theme issues. I did a series of things, and now my products show. I'm not too sure what did the trick, but if anyone else wants to try;

- I updated to 2.3.1
- Ran the `magento setup:upgrade` command
- Cleaned caches/indexes
- Set to the Blank theme (instead of Luma)
- Ran `magento setup:di:compile`
- Ran `magento deploy:mode:set production`
- Ran `magento deploy:mode:set developer`
- Cleaned caches/indexes again

And now the products are showing. Looking at the logs now, I see no critical errors anymore. I'm not sure if it was the upgrade or the setting of compilation/production mode, but it solved my issue!